# Protractor's browser.getLocationAbsUrl not working with Angular2?

Tags: angular, protractor

I am testing a Angular2 (2.0.0) app with Protractor (4.0.9).

One of my tests is calling `browser.getLocationAbsUrl()`, which gives this error message:

> [13:47:13] E/launcher - invalid element state: Failed to execute
>   'querySelector' on 'Document': The provided selector is empty.

Reading the Protractor code, getLocationAbsUrl uses the configured selector for Angular's rootElement. But for Angular2 apps, we're not setting a rootElement, but the configuration property useAllAngular2AppRoots to 'true'.

I tried setting rootElement configuration property anyways, but it is cleared by useAllAngular2AppRoots implementation.

Is  browser.getLocationAbsUrl broken for Angular2 apps?